# What language is easiest to develop command line/simple GUI for Linux?

Tags: linux, user-interface, command-line

I need to develop a large set of tools to be run from the server command line (i.e. not client-server architecture).  The systems does not have to be high-performance; I just want something that is easy to develop with.

Which technologies are out there I can use to build simple GUI to be run from the command line? I need only menus where I can select a line/check-box/enter free text in a dialog.

Edit: forgot to add, access to Mysql (i.e. drivers available) is essential.

Comment: One you know and have a development environment for...

Comment: @dmckee PHP and C# are my strongest skills right now, I do not think either is appropriate for this task (not sure yet about the php-gtk project looks somewhat as an abandoned project).

Answer (score 5):

Shell, with dialog, the old stand-by - http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807

EDIT- If it's MySQL-related, take a look at PERL-Tk and DBI.

Answer (score 3):

python + ncurses would be a good combo here.

Answer (score 2):

i like using perl's `re.pl` from the `Devel::REPL` library for quickie cli interfaces. read on a bit for my rationale before downvoting!

in this type of app it sounds like you will be doing query-type operations. these naturally lend themselves to a "repl" style interraction. `re.pl` gives you all of the goodies, namely command editing and history. all you need to write are the functions that users will call. the nice thing is that users who know perl will realize they can `use` any installed module to extend the functionality of your system on their own. i my case, i used `re.pl` to create a mysqlclient-like tool to access and display data that was being compressed in a way that the standard mysqlclient couldn't deal with.

i cite perl because it's DBI is the best database abstraction and it is what i have used....but the rationale can be extended to other tools. python's repl or any other would provide the same benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Mono for Linux](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) and write your program in C# .NET, then make it work for Linux, since Mono allows so.

Answer (score 1):

As far as graphic command line interfaces go, one of the best frameworks is [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). It abstracts away most of the ugliness associated with graphic command line applications.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say, use Python, because I like it.

But text-based interfaces are pretty much not worth it, because they seem like a good idea until you look at the details:

- There isn't really a standard keyboard navigation model for text-UIs; they all use their own scheme
- How is unicode supported? (Hint: this is nontrivial)
- What about different keyboard layouts? What key does someone press if their keyboard doesn't have, say, a "home", "end", or "Escape" ?

ncurses does not provide a widget set, only low-level operations. The answers to the above questions aren't easy.

It really shows that nobody has put much thought into keyboard-and-text-driven terminal-based UIs recently, or these would all have been solved.

Web interfaces have them solved, in fact, you can use a text-mode web browser if you like.

Modern devices like i(phone|pad)s and even cheap mobile phones have a web browser which is good enough.

It is easy to write a web application which uses a very simple style (few images, little Javascrfipt) and have it work without much effort on a variety of devices.

So I would say go with dmckee's comment "go with what you know".

By building your own terminal-based interface, you are going to box yourself into a corner in the long term.